# Kinetic Term Normalization in Quantum FIeld Theory

Tags: quantum-field-theory

Say we are given an antisymmetric two-form field: $A_{\mu\nu}$. Its kinetic term in the Lagrangian should be of the form

> $$ \mathscr{L}_{kin} = a\int d^4x \ \partial_{[\mu}A_{\nu\rho]}\partial^{[\mu}A^{\nu\rho]}$$
>   How does one determine $a$ in this case?

Personally I would use the generalized Kronecker symbol to write $ \partial_{[\mu}A_{\nu\rho]} = \frac{1}{3!}\delta_{\mu\nu\rho}^{\alpha\beta\gamma}\partial_{\alpha}A_{\beta\gamma}$ and then I would get in the $\mathscr{L}_{kin}$:
$$\mathscr{L}_{kin} = \frac{a}{(3!)^2}\int \delta_{\mu\nu\rho}^{\alpha\beta\gamma} \  \delta^{\mu\nu\rho}_{\kappa\lambda\sigma} \ \partial_{\alpha}A_{\beta\gamma} \partial^{\kappa}A^{\lambda\sigma}. $$
Contraction of the generalized Kronecker symbol would give me another $3!$ (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_delta) so I would arrive finally at a factor of $a/3!$ in front of a nicer looking (i.e. without antisymmetrizers) $$ \mathscr{L}_{kin} = \dfrac{a}{3!} \int d^4x \ \partial_{\alpha}A_{\beta\gamma}\partial^{\alpha}A^{\beta\gamma}. $$

At this point do I demand that the overall coefficient of the kinetic term should be $1/2$, yielding an awkward looking overall factor of $a = \frac{3!}{2}$ ?

Comment: Why do you think you can determine $a$ from that? As written, I think the factor does not impact the equations of motion and is thus (on a classical level) completely arbitrary unless you add other terms to the Lagrangian.

Comment: Indeed the factor is just a multiplicative constant, irrelevant to the equations of motion. I'm curious though as to how the derivation of the factor -1/4 in the usual QED Lagrangian kinetic term generalizes.

Comment: ACuriousMind is absolutely right that the normalization's up to you.  That said, there are some conventions here that people tend to follow. You may want to take a look at (B.4.12) in Polchinski's String Theory vol. 2. In his conventions, the 4 is actually 2.p! for an antisymmetric p-form.